# group by based on part of a column value in mySql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a mySql  table call details. details table is having a column call date which is having date like `2015-02-01`. There can be multiple rows from a same date.

I want to find how many rows `COUNT()` it contains for each month of the year.

for example,

```
'568', '192.168.1.100', '790', '1.00', '2014-11-14'    
'569', '192.168.1.100', '780', '1.00', '2014-11-14'  
'699', '192.168.1.100', '780', '1.00', '2014-11-16'
'767', '192.168.1.102', '780', '1.00', '2014-12-15'   
'768', '192.168.1.102', '780', '1.00', '2014-12-15'
```

this should give COUNT like:

```
 '2014-11-' as 3
 '2014-12-' as 2
```

How can i do it using a sql select query.

Comment: Please create an SQLfiddle for your case

Comment: Create a table with your sample data (http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html) and post the current query, makes things easier. Right now I don't know how your table Looks like but I feel like there is a solution.

Answer (score 4):

```
Select DATE_FORMAT(My_Call_Date_Field, '%Y-%m') as MyYearAndMonth, Count(*) as MyCount
From My_Call_Details_Table Group By  DATE_FORMAT(My_Call_Date_Field, '%Y-%m')
```

You can also use the [CAST function of MySql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html).

```
Select substr(convert(My_Call_Date_Field, CHAR), 1, 7) as MyYearAndMonth, Count(*) From My_Call_Details_Table Group By substr(convert(My_Call_Date_Field, CHAR), 1, 7) Order By substr(convert(My_Call_Date_Field, CHAR), 1, 7)
```

In response to additional info specific to your case, as seen in your comment to the previous answer by Ed King: here it is :

```
 SELECT DATE_FORMAT(detailtable.date, '%Y-%m') , AVG(detailtable.loadstate) as "load",count(detailtable.loadstate) as "count" from ruby_snmp.detailtable where ipaddtress='192.168.1.102' and date LIKE '2014-12-%' GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(detailtable.date, '%Y-%m')
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I learned how to get the use of mySql Date object from your example. It is the turning point for my question!!. Finally my query is working perfectly...

Comment: May I request you to mark one of the responses, either the one by Ed King or the one by me, as the answer to this question, so that the question is marked as resolved ?

Comment: I got the answers by combining both of your answers. So credit should goes to both of you. I cant exactly nominate one answer as the correct answer.

Comment: Hey, thats okay. In the interest of the community having a resolved question, I am quite okay with Ed King's answer being marked as the correct one, if thats okay with you. :-) :-)

Answer (score 1):

Convert to month and year using mysql functions, group and count:

```
SELECT month(calldate) as m, year(calldate) as y, count(*) 
FROM calldetails 
GROUP by m, y;
```

Given the additional information, I would do the following:

```
SELECT YEAR(detailtable.date) as y,
    MONTH(detailtable.date) as m, 
    AVG(detailtable.loadstate) as "load",
    count(detailtable.loadstate) as "count" 
FROM ruby_snmp.detailtable 
WHERE ipaddtress='192.168.1.102' and date LIKE '2014-12-%' 
GROUP BY y, m;
```

The format variables y and m would be disregarded, but need to be there for the group to work.  You can add the FORMAT function to give the specific YYYY-MM as was mentioned in the second post, or you can handle data presentation in the program / report writer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. this is my query SELECT detailtable.date, AVG(detailtable.loadstate) as "load",count(detailtable.loadstate) as "count" from ruby_snmp.detailtable where ipaddtress='192.168.1.102' and date LIKE '2014-12-%' GROUP BY detailtable.date; but this should get the count for each day, how can i user your answer for get the count for each month... please help